# Echarts4r + Boxplot + Jitter points: How to make this combination work properly?

Tags: r, boxplot, echarts, echarts4r

How to make this combination work? I can create the boxplot. I can create a scatter plot with jittered points, but I cannot put them together. Does anyone have any idea? The idea is to continue using echarts library.

```
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

echart1 <- mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  e_charts(cyl) |>
  e_scatter_(
    "hp",
    jitter_factor = 2
  ) 

echart2 <- mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  e_charts() |>
  e_boxplot(hp)
```

Comment: not exactly sure what you want and dont know r but [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=boxplot-light-velocity) sounds about like it does what you are looking for in echarts?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps after so much time has passed, but I just ran across your question.

The reason it isn't working in any way that may be considered obvious is because `echarts` always categorizes the grouping axis when creating a box plot. When you have a scatter plot, you need two numerical axes for it to be meaningful. The great news here is that you can still do this, you just need to "explain" it to `echarts`.

Let's start with your boxplot, that provides the look you want (for example, the x-axis does not start at zero). Now, since you are going to jitter the points, I suggest that you don't plot the outliers.

Next is adding the jitter plot. You'll need to assign it to a different x-axis. The first is "0", so assign it to "1". Then tell `echarts` how to restrain that axis (e.g., don't start at 0) and here you can hide this new axis.

I made the scatter points large to make them obvious.

Starting with that plot you had for the boxplot...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  e_charts(cyl) %>% 
  e_boxplot(hp, outliers = F) %>%  # <--turning outlier plotting off
  e_scatter(hp, jitter_factor = 2, symbol_size = 10, # <-- made points HUGE
            x_index = 1,     # <---- give it a new x-axis
            legend = F) %>%  # <---- no legends please
  e_x_axis(index = 1, min = 3, max = 9, # confine to 3 <-> 9
           show = F)                    # don't show axis
```

[image]